# Napili template custom Login page selection

Tags: napili, community-builder, lightning-community

I am setting Napili based customer community in Salesforce. Want to change the login page preference but I am not getting any other pages to select.

What might be the reason? How to get pages in look-up search?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried typing in first two characters of the page name with an * followed and click Go yet?

Comment: @jai Chaturvedi: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Basically what I found that if we want to bring the pages here in look-up then we have to create pages in Sites. Go to community administration > Pages > Site.com studio > create a Page Template.

Now you have to do setting in Site configuration > Default pages > select the new page as the Login page. Also, the page created as "Page Templates" appears in look-up. 

This was my investigation but still, there were some discrepancies observed. You can try and see if it works for you. Let me know your findings.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For Napili based community you need to customize the Login page that comes by default instead of trying to change it to a custom page. Below link from salesforce states the same

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_page.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.6

If your community uses the Customer Service (Napili) template, the login page assigned to the community by default is called Login. Use Community Builder to customize its appearance.

You can totally customize it and add your own lightning components to it